# Load image into div, PHP and jQuery invloved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is an assignment that I need to make to complete my PHP course in college. I've spent already the entire day on this, trying different things (ajax jquery loading for example). I'm fairly sure I need to head down the road I am currently on. The `onclick` in the `a href` works, I tried it with an alert I made into the script part.
However, I can't figure out how I can load the image into the div `photoHolder`.
This photoholder should contain the thumbnail I click on. Ofcourse it should be dynamic. So when I upload image and it created an automatic thumbnail, the original picture should be showed when I click the thumbnail.
I also need to add comments and rating, but let's get this down first.

I surely hope, after all this is a site where I learned alot, that someone can help me.

The piece of PHP which has the `onclick` in the `href`:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="makeBigger();"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['album'], '/', $image['id'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / H:i', $image['timestamp']), '" /></a> 


            [<a href="delete_image.php?image_id=', $image['id'], '">x</a>]';
    }
}
?>

    <div id="photoHolder"></div>`
```

This is the jQuery part located in my included header.php

```
    function makeBigger() {
           // This function needs to load the picture with a max width of
           // 300px into the "photoHolder" div located on view_album.php
    }
```

Ofcourse it's empty now, 'cause I wanted to start with a clean sheet.

If it's difficult to read, here is a Gist I made for you (`#photoHolder` is on line 30 of view_album.php)

[Gist for you](https://gist.github.com/pim013/7107280)

**EDIT**
If it wasn't clear: I need to load the bigger image, located in my uploads folder. This is an example link of how I load it in a new tab when clicking the thumb:

```
<a href="uploads/', $image['album'], '/', $image['id'], '.', $image['ext'], '"></a>
```

Comment: Well problem number one here is that you don't have any jquery. You need to include the jquery library for that. You can tell something is jquery at a glance via the $ global variable like $(Do stuff).likethis({triggeringthisfunction}); - jQuery isn't that simple so I'm not sure why they are assigning it for an intro to PHP class.

Comment: How do I get the URL of the larger image?

Comment: @baordog Why would you say that jQuery not being used would be a problem? Javascript is sufficient for what the OP wants to achieve. jQuery just for one function would be an overkill.

Comment: @user2540773 my advice is : do not write JS with PHP.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta because he references Jquery in the question. I think it's part of his assignment.

Comment: `foreach($images as $image)` -> PHP

Comment: @SunnyRGupta his `$images` variable holds an array of image urls. He is iterating through the array collection and rendering html links. with javascript/jquery you add additional functionaly, whereby clicking the link loads the image into a div on the fly.

Comment: Correct, I'm just pointing out to @baordog that the $ variables are not just for jQuery, in the question above, $images is in a php script (see `echo`). Also, the loading the image in a new div can be done using simple Javascript too. No need for jQuery on that.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Thanks everyone for the answers! Can you tell me how to achieve this without having to use jQuery? jQuery isn't part of my assignment. PHP is the only requirement and I am free to solve any problem with any language.

Answer (score 3):

using jQuery (http://jquery.com/), you can solve it like this:

Add this between your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

replace this:

`onclick="makeBigger();"`

with this:

`onclick="makeBigger(this);"`

and here's the javascript function:

```
function makeBigger(imageLink)
{
    // get Image URL
    var imageUrl = $(imageLink).find('img').attr('src');

    // load big image
    $('photoHolder').html('<img src="'+imageUrl  +'" width="300" />');
}
```

**EDIT :**
Alternatively, you could add replace:

`<a href="#" onclick="makeBigger();">`

with:

`<a href="#" class="imageLink">`

and your function would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.imageLink').click(function()
    {
        // get Image URL
        var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        // load big image
        $('photoHolder').html('<img src="'+ imageUrl  +'" width="300" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Good but try to avoid inline JS. Instead use event handler like `.on('click',function(){});`

Comment: Nice solution to the problem! +1

Comment: Not sure why, by the code block removed the # from my post. This is the correct line: `$('#photoHolder').html( ... )`

Comment: Thanks @LatheesanKanes ! I have two problems now though: The image load and disappears right away, it's like a flicker. And I need to load the full-size version of the image shown on the thumbnail, not just make the thumbnail bigger.  So I need the picture that is located in my uploads/$albumid/$imageid.$ext

Comment: @LatheesanKanes I've edited my original post, hope it can help you. 'Cause like I said, your solution works, only it flickers (but why?) and it created a bigger size image of the thumb.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Maybe you know a new solution aswell?